# Joomla 2.5 and Virtuemart 3 installation problems

Tags: joomla-2.5, mysql, virtuemart, sql

I've tried installing Joomla 2.5 and Virtuemart 3 (full install download from Virtuemart's website) and I went through the installation process ok. However I've had a lot of errors come up and don't understand it at all. It looks like it could be missing files or file permissions. I've posted pictures to show some of the errors coming up.

Can someone help me with this please?

[image]

enter image description here

Comment: If you're creating a new website with VirtueMart, please use Joomla 3.x as it's currently the latest stable version. Joomla 2.5 is no longer supported, therefore you will most likely not get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it myself. I set all the permissions for the folders in the com_virtuemart folder in the administration folder to 777, and created image folders as specified. All errors are now gone.

Comment: Sorry but this is a bad idea. All directories should be 755 and files should be 644

Comment: Which one is the one for a file to have "writable" status on all permissions? Since that was the one I wanted to change.